# Two elementary equivalent $L$-structures of a first order language $L$ have the same cardinality if one of them is finite.

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

Let $M,N$ are elementary equivalent $L$-structures where $L$ is a first-order language.  If $M$ is finite , then how to prove that $|M|=|N|$ ?

I was thinking like this. Let $|M|=n$. To prove $|N|=n$, I have to somehow write down the fact that $M$ has at least $n$ many elements by using a sentence (closed formula). If I can do that, then $M$ and $N$ proves same $L$-sentences would give me that $N$ has at least $n$ many elements. Now if $N$ had more than $n$ many elements then it would have at least $n+1$ many elements, then again using an $L$-sentence we would have $M$ has at least $n+1$ many elements , contradiction ! Hence that would prove $|N|=n$. But unfortunately I'm unable to write the fact that $M$  has at least $n$ many elements by using an $L$-sentence. (Perhaps if we could write $M$ has exactly $n$ many elements using some $L$-sentence, that would also work, but that seems even difficult)

Please help.

Comment: Hint: $\exists x \exists y ( x \not = y \wedge \forall z (z = x \vee z=y))$ is a sentence which holds of a structure iff the structure has exactly two elements.

Comment: @Nagase: Ah right ... I can see how to make it work for $n$ elements but the formula will be very ugly to write ... do you know of a neat way to write it ?

Comment: Better: if $M$ and $N$ are elementarily equivalent and one is finite, then they're isomorphic!

Comment: See, for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/238909/7062

Comment: @users - well, you can abbreviate each component. For instance, say $\phi_n := \forall z (z=x_1 \vee \dots \vee z=x_n)$. Similarly, you can define $\psi_n$ to be the existential part.

Answer (score 1):

We have that 
$$
M\models\exists x_1...x_n\left(\bigwedge_{i,j\leq n, \ j\neq i}x_i\neq x_j\right)
$$ 
then 
$$
N\models\exists x_1...x_n\left(\bigwedge_{i,j\leq n, \ j\neq i}x_i\neq x_j\right)
$$

Now, if
$$
N\models\exists x_{n+1}\exists x_1...x_n(\bigwedge_{i\leq n} x_{n+1}\neq x_i)
$$

then 
$$
M\models\exists x_{n+1}\exists x_1...x_n(\bigwedge_{i\leq n} x_{n+1}\neq x_i)
$$
 but this is a contradiction, so $|N|=n$.

Comment: I think you want the universal quntifiers to also be existentials in the last two sentences. As written, they're false in every structure , since $x_i$ could be $x_{n+1}$ for all $i<n$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman yes, is truth, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let

$\phi_n := \forall z(z = x_1 \vee \dots z=x_n)$.

Let

$\psi_n := \exists x_1 \dots \exists x_n(x_1 \not = x_2 \wedge \dots \wedge x_1 \not = x_n \wedge \dots \wedge x_{n-1} \not = x_n \wedge \phi_n)$.

Then $M \models \psi_n$ iff $M$ has *exactly* $n$ elements.

So let now $M$ and $N$ be two elementary equivalent structures. Let $|M| = n$. Since $|M|=n$, it follows that $M \models \psi_n$. But $M$ and $N$ are elementary equivalent, so $N \models \psi_n$. Thus, $|N| = n$, as required.

Comment: How does this mesh up with the Löwenheim–Skolem paradox?  Doesn't the paradox only work precisely because "$M\models \psi_n$ iff $M$ has exactly $n$ elements" is false?

Comment: @Squirtle No, the (combination of the upward and downward versions of the) Löwenheim-Skolem theorem says that, if a theory has a model of an infinite cardinality, then it has a model in any infinite cardinality. It says nothing about theories with models of finite cardinality, which is the case here.